# How catch exceptions and store in a ArrayList

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, collections, throwable

I am trying to catch exceptions generated while executing some methods in a list.
I have created a different POJO class extending throwable class.

```
public class ErrorDetails extends  Throwable implements Serializable {


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private Exception errorDescription;


    public Exception getErrorDescription() {
        return errorDescription;
    }


    public void setErrorDescription(Exception errorDescription) {
        this.errorDescription = errorDescription;
    }
```

But still I cannot capture the exception in this manner.

```
private List<ErrorDetails> hello=new ArrayList<ErrorDetails>();
 catch (Exception e) {
            hello.add(e);
```

Comment: what? where is the exception thrown? or where you are initializing the list. Paste the complete code with try catch block and add some print statement or breakpoint in catch to see if at all exception is thrown

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense, but in case its relevant, your `ErrorDetails` type does not extend `Exception`, so would not be caught in a `catch (Exception)` block.

Comment: @khelwood I have tried with extending Exception also. It does not work.

Comment: What doesn't work? It's not clear what you're trying to do. Post a [mre].

Comment: @Optional My aim is to add all the exception in the list.

Comment: Subhranil Sengupta like @khelwood said, give a reproducible example, a runnable java program to explain your problem instead of just snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ErrorDetails is one specific type of Throwable. If you declare a list of ErrorDetails you can't add exceptions or errors in it. Change your code to use a list of Exception instead:

```
List<Exception> hello = new ...
```

I don't see a point to have your ErrorDetails class but in case you want to keep it, remove "extends Throwable" or replace it with something else. Throwable is meant to be a parent class only for Exception and Error.

Comment: I have removed Throwable and replaced it with Exception.